# Does Barack Obama have an aunt who was a homeless illegal alien that used government housing for 10 years?

Tags: united-states, barack-obama

Just found [this one on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=417306771671861&set=a.392233420845863.89075.392213267514545&type=1&theater). The people making the claim have 11k page likes (26th November 2012).

[image: Barack Obama's Aunt]

> She lived in a homeless shelter for 2 years.
>   Lived in Government housing for 10 years.
>   As an illegal alien.
>   Her nephew is a multimillionaire.
>   He claimed $87,000 in charitable donations.
>   But never gave her a dime.
>   His name is Barack Obama.

Comment: **Removed off topic comments** - take political opinions to the [chat] please :-)

Comment: If he had given her money I'm sure the claim would have been "Scandal! Obama supports illegal immigrant relative!"

Answer (score 42, accepted):

That's largely right. Her name is [Zeituni Onyango](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeituni_Onyango).

1. She lived in a homeless shelter for 2 years. [source](http://www.boston.com/news/local/massachusetts/articles/2010/09/21/obamas_aunt_says_system_was_at_fault/)

   > Zeituni Onyango, blamed “the system’’ for her controversial living arrangement in Boston public housing as an illegal immigrant
2. Lived in government housing for 10 years.

   *This source covers 2004-2010* [source](http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-dyn/content/article/2010/05/17/AR2010051703817.html)

   > Onyango moved to the United States in 2000. Her first asylum request was rejected, and she was ordered deported in 2004. But she did not leave the country and continued to live in public housing in Boston.
3. As an illegal alien. [source](http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-dyn/content/article/2010/05/17/AR2010051703817.html)

   > Onyango's status as an illegal immigrant was revealed just days before Obama was elected in November 2008.
4. Her 'nephew' is a multimillionare.

   Yes, he's a multimillionaire. [source](http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/fact-checker/post/obamas-gifts-to-charity-just-1-percent/2012/02/14/gIQAXuMDER_blog.html)

   > In 2009, the president’s taxable income was about $5.5 million

   However, to be precise, he is her *half*-nephew. [source](http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-dyn/content/article/2010/05/17/AR2010051703817.html)

   > Kenya native Zeituni Onyango, 57, is the half-sister of Obama's late father
5. He has claimed $87,000 in charitable contributions.

   The year isn't specified. In recent years, the number is much higher. [source](http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/fact-checker/post/obamas-gifts-to-charity-just-1-percent/2012/02/14/gIQAXuMDER_blog.html)

   > In 2010, for instance, [...] he gave $245,075 in gifts to charity. [...]
   >
   > In 2009, [... he] listed $329,100 in charitable contributions on his tax return and also directed the Nobel Prize Committee to give his $1.4 million prize directly to 10 charities
   >
   > [...]
   >
   > 2005: $77,315 to charity out of income of $1.66 million (4.6 percent)
   >
   > 2004: $2,500 out of $207,647 (1.2 percent)
   >
   > 2003: $3,400 out of $238,327 (1.4 percent)
   >
   > 2002: $1,050 out of $259,394 (0.4 percent)
6. But never gave her a dime. [source](http://youtu.be/cSavIWCJiUo?t=2m50s)

   According to this interview of her, no.

   > "Nor, has [Obama] stepped in financially to get her off of public assistance."
7. His name is Barack Obama. (this is kind of given and undisputed.)

Comment: On point 3, "As an illegal alien", if an immigration court granted her asylum in 2010, that may suggest she was not previously an illegal alien even if an earlier court thought she was. If the details of the decision have not been published, we may never know.